# Access Ticker stream

Tags: ios, facebook, ticker

is there anyway I can access Ticker in my app? If so how can I do it? A quick example would be amazing.

Btw, my app is for iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't currently an api endpoint for accessing the ticker. I'm guessing/hoping one will be released eventually

Comment: I hope someone come up with a JS script to manually create that feed for your app. the down side would be asking user to login with their fb user/pass